Why is the viewport all red?
I recently downloaded the latest version of Blender to work on a new project and there is a little timer at the bottom of the screen. As the timer goes up the screen starts becoming red. At about 15 minutes it's completely filled making any work impossible as shown in the second image below.
I have no idea why this is happening and how to stop it. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.



First off, no this is not an expected behavior for native Blender. Did you download Blender from anywhere besides blender.org? What addons do you have enabled?

Did you install the non-Blender "You Are Autosave" addon or any similar thing? Seems like this error to me: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/130868 All it wants you to do is save your file, then you can work on. Why do you install addons when you don't know what they do?

The question is not about a bug. This is apparently intended functionality of a very poorly designed add-on. I think this question should not be closed as it can be useful for people facing this issue with the exact add-on that has "Auto Save" in its name but actually does this nonsense as intended functionality.

As already commented you probably have installed this addon:
https://extensions.blender.org/add-ons/you-are-autosave/
In order to solve the problem open blender preferences, go to addons tab and search for this addon "you are autosave".
Unsinstall the addon.


could be nice to mention that it's how the addon is meant to work and explain how you are supposed to work with it. Otherwise, just saying to uninstalling it will make people think it's a bug or an unwanted addon.
